# Having issue when playing Smash Ultimate in dock

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-switch, super-smash-bros-ultimate

I would be playing Super Smash Bros Ultimate on the dock and during gameplay the TV screen goes like a greyish black color like it disconnected BUT the music is still playing and going to the home page doesn't fix it. Please note this "bug" only happens while playing SSBU as I've tested with other games and this only happens when playing docked (TV mode). The TV screen doesn't show the "no signal" screen saver either and I'm not using a monitor. I'm suspecting an issue with my gamecard maybe.

Comment: Do you have any friends with Smash Ultimate that you could borrow their game card to test it? Perhaps a rental service nearby to grab a copy of the game?

Comment: I currently dont have any rental services nearby or friends with this game. Although ive tested playing all the other games i have and cannot find an issue. I am currently testing wither or not it only happens during multiplayer since i only play smash on the dock when with friends.

Comment: Also whoever fixed the grammer on my original post. Thanks